# Unindent lines in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2, text-editor, sublimetext

You know when you have a bunch of text marked and predd TAB the text moves to the right (I can't remember what this is called...). How can I make the text do the opposite?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is like other editors. Just try <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>. ;)

Comment: You actually need the `shift_tab_unindent` setting to be set to `true` for this to work. I think it's false by default.

Comment: @tombruijn it is off by default, but that only means that it works only partially: `By default, shift+tab will only unindent if the selection spans multiple lines. When pressing shift+tab at other times, it'll insert a tab character - this allows tabs to be inserted when tab_completion is enabled. Set this to true to make shift+tab always unindent, instead of inserting tabs.`

Comment: you can also do

Answer (score 24):

The commands you're talking about are called "indent" and "unindent".

### Mac

Indent: <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>

Unindent: <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>

### Others

Indent: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>

Unindent: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

You can try <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to un-indent multiple selected lines. If you want to un-indent a single line where the cursor is in, you need to set

```
 "shift_tab_unindent": true,
```

in your user settings.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> didn't work for Makefiles in Sublime Text 3 for me. So I've added this keybinding:

```
[
{ "keys": ["shift+tab"], "command": "unindent", "args": {"single_line":true} }
]
```